# Find date columns in R. Date column have different date-formats. Replace all date format to dd-mmm-yyyy

Tags: r, date

Creating a function that identifies only date columns in a data frame. And change their format to DD-MMM_YYYY(01-Jan-2020)

```
 data <- data.frame(Name = c("A","B","C"),
                        Col2 = c("01-01-2020","01-Feb-2020","31/05/2020"),
                col3 = c("05-Feb-2020","13/April/2020","2020-09-17"), 
                        Col4 = c("XYZ","REW","RRRR"),
                        col5 = c("01-Mar-2020","01/01/2019","2020-01-12")) 

func <- function(data) { }
```

Expected output

[image]

**NOTE : The function needs to identify which columns are date and change its format to yyyy-mm-dd**

Comment: Please always ensure your data is copy pastable.

Comment: Noted! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `tidyverse`(see Note):

```
    date_parser <- function(column){
   if(any(grepl("[-]",column))){

 format(parse_date_time(column,orders = c("dmy","dby","ymd")),"%d-%b-%Y")
     }

   else column
 }
   df %>% 
   mutate_at(-1,~ stringr::str_replace_all(.,"\\/","-")) %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(~date_parser(.))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Name  Col2        col3        Col4  col5       
  <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr> <chr>      
1 A     01-Jan-2020 05-Feb-2020 XYZ   01-Mar-2020
2 B     01-Feb-2020 13-Apr-2020 REW   01-Jan-2019
3 C     31-May-2020 17-Sep-2020 RRRR  12-Jan-2020
```

**NOTE**:

This is not an actual date, you can convert it again with `lubridate` although I doubt `dttm` supports mixed dates. Hence as far as I know, you'll still resort to characters.

Comment: The result should be in 'dd-mmm-yyyy' format. (eg 01-Jan-2020)

Comment: It Worked! Thanks

Comment: When the input file is in '.csv' format, the above code works fine. However, when the input file is in '.xlsx' format the above code produces NA inside of dates. Any Idea?

Comment: It might be hard for me to tell. Which function are you using to read in the data and what does the data look like?

Comment: That got resolved! Thanks. I have some other columns in my dataset that contain "-" symbol. So now those are also getting affected by the above function

Comment: Could you ask a new question with that data and link it to this and explain the issue there?! It's kinda hard for me to know all possible scenarios without the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61546592/error-in-replacing-data-in-r-by-identifying-date-columns

Comment: I have asked here